# What's the proper iOS UI for switching between 2 views?

Tags: mobile, navigation, ios

There two different screens, Live and Leaderboard, and I need to switch between them.

Is there any sort of iOS standard for handling the UI for that?

Right now I've just got a button at the top right called "View" where a user can tap and then select which view they want (Live or Leaderboard), but it feels a little off. Not sure if it's the word "View" or if it's something else that's bothering me.

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming you don't want to use a navigation bar, or there's already a navigation bar in place?

Comment: Already a nav bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about adding a `UISegmentedControl` to switch views as the App Store does?

### Old App Store with two view Selections:

[image: Old App Store Screenshot - 2 views]

### New App Store with three view selections:

[image: New App Store Screenshot - 3 views]

This was also [asked on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047114/how-do-i-use-a-uisegmentedcontrol-to-switch-views/) from a programming perspective.

Comment: The BBC iPlayer iPad app uses this too (in their house colours)